# Non-gradient methods in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Good day everyone!
I have an idea (prototyped on Python) of non-gradient training method for specific neural networks. I want to re-write it on Tensorflow to make computations on GPU. But all documentation of TF is about gradient computation, propagation and applying. Is it possible to run any non-gradient training method?

Comment: What is the training method like? Only when you try to minimize the loss using an optimizer in TensorFlow are the gradients updated

Comment: There's nothing that says you have to use an optimizer. You could use it just for GPU computations.

Comment: I have activation functions like: y={-1, if x<=-1; x, if |x|<1; 1, if x>=1}
We can call this three cases "regions". I'm calculating shifts of each weight that leads to region change in any neuron of the net. So, there is no gradient back propagation, but there is propagation of two shifts of weights.

Comment: As matrianwars and chris_anderson pointed out, you don't have to use the built-in gradient descent optimizer. Have you tried to implement it with tensorflow and could you be more specific about what you think the specific limitation of tensorflow is that prevent you implementing it?

Comment: Ok, so how can I set which variables will be back propagated? For example, how can I set that on the last layer all shifts of weights have to be 1, on previous -- 2 and so on?
 I'm sorry about this stupid questions, but I really don't understand well how TF training works.

Comment: You might want to look into gradient_override_map, which would allow you to implement your custom backpropgation for any operation. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph.gradient_override_map

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me example of its usage? It should be done in training function of my model, right?

Comment: Or I should create my own optimizer and make this changes to the graph there?